# Force of tension on both sides of one string- 2 questions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

Here's something I want to ask you guys about:

[image]
<sub>(source: [mechanikaklasyczna.prv.pl](http://mechanikaklasyczna.prv.pl/hid_mc_gfx/graphic/80.jpg))</sub>

Many times downward N1 and N2 are ignored in exercises. Why?

If forces of tension are balanced by each other, why won't objects just fall?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the circular disk is a friction-less pulley that's in equilibrium/at rest. If so N1 = N2 and the forces of tension are balanced. Once again assuming the strings are not stretchable the objects will not fall because of the tension in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Newton’s 2nd law is about the all the forces on a single body; Newton’s 3rd law is about a single force acting on two different bodies.

In this case, the $N_1$ and $N_2$ on the left-hand string are acting on a single body so we use N2L:

$$N_1 - N_2 = (0) a$$

where we assume it’s a massless string. In that case, regardless of whether to string a accelerating or not, the two tensions are equal.

We can do a similar balance for the blocks, but they’re not massless: an acceleration requires a difference of forces.

Answer (score 0):

They won't fall because N1 and N2 are equal to one another. If they weren't the system would move until it does become equal.

I think the confusion is that if those two forces are "cancelled", they should not contribute to the system at all. However, the "cancellation" or balance due to the tension is what actually keeps the system from falling.